# Stripe source still usable after 3ds payment

Tags: stripe-payments

Currently I am using the below to get a sourceID

```
stripe.createSource(card, {
    usage: 'single_use'
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result.source.id)
})
```

Then I pass this sourceID to the server to be used to create a 3ds source.

```
source3ds = await createSource({
  type: 'three_d_secure',
  amount: PaymentService._toStripeAmount(opts.amount),
  currency: opts.currency,
  three_d_secure: {
    card: opts.sourceId // HERE!
  },
  redirect: {
    return_url: redirectUrl.toString()
  },
})
```

I notice that once this happens and even after a successful 3ds payment, the sourceId remains usable, I think its because making a 3ds source out from this source does not count as using this source?

Is this correct? If so it does not seem very secure since someone who gets this token can make many requests using it?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that the original card source does remain chargeable even after using it to create a 3DS source. Generally, sources with `type=card` will always have `status=chargeable`.

The card source (like any other resource in Stripe's API) is specific to your Stripe account though, so it can only be used to create charges using your account's secret API key. So even if the source's ID (`src_...`) is leaked, it's not a security issue. In general, Stripe resource IDs are not considered sensitive as they can only be used with your secret API key.

As the name implies, the secret API key is sensitive and should be kept, well, secret :)